# What is the best practice if I want to forward a variable to be moved in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

```
#include <utility>
class SomeObject {
// ...Object Definition
};

void B(SomeObject& so)
{
    SomeObject movedTo = std::move(so);
}

void A(SomeObject& so)
{
    B(so);
}

int main()
{
    SomeObject movedFrom;
    A(movedFrom);

    return 0;
}
```

For example, now I have two functions A and B. Function A may first do something, then pass the argument `so` to function B. In function B, I will move the passed argument `so`. What confused me a lot is that there is another way to do this:

```
#include <utility>
class SomeObject {
// ...Object Definition
};

void B(SomeObject&& so)
{
    SomeObject movedTo = std::move(so);
}

void A(SomeObject&& so)
{
    B(std::move(so));
}

int main()
{
    SomeObject movedFrom;
    A(std::move(movedFrom));

    return 0;
}
```

In the second version, the parameter of function A and B are rvalue references. Both of these codes compiles, and both of them work well. So, which one is the better practice of doing such kind of thing?

Comment: The first one is a bad practice, because a caller does not expect moving of an argument passed by a reference. It is more obvious if SomeObject is std::unique_ptr.

Comment: This is a good guideline how to do argument passing: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f15-prefer-simple-and-conventional-ways-of-passing-information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void B(SomeObject& so)
{
    SomeObject movedTo = std::move(so);
```

This is a bad design. Don't move from an lvalue reference parameter. That is going to miselead programmers who make reasonable assumptions based on the parameter type and won't expect the argument that they pass to be moved from.

> In the second version, the parameter of function A and B are rvalue references.

This is much better. It is reasonable to expect an rvalue reference to be moved from.

> So, which one is the better practice of doing such kind of thing?

The second one, without a doubt.

---

> What is the best practice if I want to forward

You aren't "forwarding" in the common use of the word. What is typically called forwarding is to copy from an lvalue and move from an rvalue. You can achieve that by using a value parameter instead of a reference:

```
void B(SomeObject so)
{
    SomeObject movedTo = std::move(so);
}
```

This way the caller can move an object argument with low cost, or copy it when they don't want their argument to be moved from.

```
SomeObject so;
B(so);            // copy
B(std::move(so)); // move
```

Comment: Probably it is bad design, but if a parameter of a function I call is known to be a non-`const` lvalue reference, why should I expect it doesn't modify the argument? Moving from is still a modification, after all.

Comment: @Enlico Most people would expect it to be modified. In fact, they would assume that it will have some useful state given by the function. Moving from an object generally leaves it in the opposite of a useful state.

Comment: Yeah, but telling what that "useful state" is, I think, it's up to the doc of that function; and `SomeObject` could in general be left in a good state even after the move (a state telling "my resources have been moved away from me"). In other words, I can move from a non-`const` parameter if I know what I'm doing with it and document what I do. After all, `SomeObject` is not a template parameter, so my function cannot be used on types I don't know how to move properly. No?

Comment: @Enlico Why not change the function to `void B(void* so)` then? After all, since you can document what it does, then what's the point of types?

Comment: Because I don't know the type of the pointed-to object that `B`'s been passed. How can I document that? However, I'm not arguing on your claim that moving from lvalue ref params is bad design, I'm just saying that I don't make assumptions on what happens to those params, but I go to the doc to read what happens.

Comment: @Enlico `How can I document that?` Like this: `/* type is SomeObject */`. `I don't make assumptions` Perhaps you aren't making assumptions about what functions do, but are you perhaps making assumption that your colleagues won't make assumptions? It's bad for correct usage of function to depend solely on reading the documentation when the type system has a way to express the meaning without the need of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is quite helpful for me! :)